# Grid non-responsive horizontally on one side

Tags: css

I have tried searching for an answer to why this is happening, but so far no luck in getting an answer that has worked.  When decreasing the size of the window, the left side of my second nested grid moves over my navigation bar.  I'm sure it's something very simple but don't have the experience to spot it.

The nested grid should collapse on both the left and right until it hits the @media query break-point.

```
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);

}


 @media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .box1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 14 ;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  position: fixed;

  }
}


@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .box2 {

  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  position: relative;

  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/BenJohannson/pen/XGXQzB

Comment: You haven't limited the width of your `main`...what else are you expecting? Also fixed position divs don't align to css-grid...they are only aligned to the viewport.

Comment: It looks like you're using several grids adjacent to one another, rather than one grid with multiple cells. I find it helpful to sketch out what the page *should* look like on paper before starting -- it should be just one grid. I see you're using grid-start and grid-end and such. When you're starting out with grid, especially for a layout like this, you might want to try grid-template-areas first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas

Comment: Thank you for attempting to help.